# User Access Control while using SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth (https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth) library with  Zend Framework 2 for my project. After successful Logged in I am redirecting user to another controller. Now I would like to block user to access that controller's view page through using URL while user is not logged in .

Can anyone say how can I do that??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a guru at ZF2 but I would recommend looking at bjyAuthorize with zfcuser using route OR controller gaurds https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize
There is a bit of setup/config but so far, for me, it's a great way to perform the ACL.
Note: I am having some trouble with my own implementation of ScnSocialAuth so I'm not saying this is your silver bullet. Will post my own question elsewhere.

UPDATE:
The alternative is to use the standard zfcuser authentication methods in the controller or view
https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki/How-to-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in